# Is it possible to use an item arg passed to a macro as a method?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I'm trying to create a macro that generates a `struct` that provides a set of methods that are passed into the macro. For example, calling:

```
create_impl!(StructName, fn foo() -> u32 { return 432 })
```

should generate an empty struct `StructName` that provides the method `foo()`.

My initial attempt at this uses the `item` macro arg type. However, when I try and use an `item` in the rule, I get the following compiler error:

```
error: expected one of `const`, `default`, `extern`, `fn`, `pub`, `type`, `unsafe`, or `}`, found `fn foo() -> u32 { return 42; }`
  --> src/lib.rs:40:13
   |
40 |           $($function)*
   |             ^^^^^^^^^
```

Is it possible to use `item` arguments to define methods in generated structs this way? Is there something I'm missing?

Here's the full macro I've defined:

```
macro_rules! create_impl {

  ($struct_name:ident, $($function:item),*) => {
      struct $struct_name {
      }

      impl $struct_name {
          // This is the part that fails.
          $($function)*
      }
  };

}
```

Comment: I think that *methods* are not items at all. When I change `fn foo()` to `fn foo(self)`, I get *error: expected one of `::` or `:`, found `)`* (the same error happens if you write that outside a macro).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is "no, you can't use the `item` matcher for a method".

According to the [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/reference.html#items), items are the top level things in a crate or module, so functions, types, and so on.  While a `struct` or `impl` block is an item, the things inside them aren't.  Even though syntactically, a method definition looks identical to a top level function, that doesn't make it an item.

The way Rust's macro system works is that once a fragment has been parsed as an `item`, e.g. using `$foo:item`, it's then forever an `item`; it's split back into tokens for reparsing once the macro is expanded.

The result of this is that `$foo:item` can only be in the macro's output in item position, which generally means top-level.

There are a couple of alternatives.

The simplest is to use the good old `tt` (token tree) matcher.  A token tree is either a non-bracket token or a sequence of tokens surrounded by balanced brackets; so `$(foo:tt)*` matches anything.  However, that means it will gobble up commas too, so it's easier to just add braces around each item:

```rs
macro_rules! create_impl {

  ($struct_name:ident, $({ $($function:tt)* }),*) => {
      struct $struct_name {
      }

      impl $struct_name {
          $($($function)*)*
      }
  };

}
```

Then you have to use it with the extra braces:

```rs
create_impl!(StructName, { fn foo() -> u32 { return 432 } }, { fn bar() -> u32 { return 765 } });
```

You can also just match the syntax you want directly, rather than delegating to the `item` matcher:

```rs
macro_rules! create_impl2 {
    ($struct_name:ident, $(fn $fname:ident($($arg:tt)*) -> $t:ty $body:block),*) => {
      struct $struct_name {
      }

      impl $struct_name {
          $(fn $fname($($arg)*) -> $t $body)*
      }
    }
}
```

Of course since it's explicit, that means that if you want to support functions without a return type, you need to add another case to your macro.